# UNET Change Texture of child object for clients

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I have tried multiple techniques, but still no result. The host is able to change the color, but not for the client players. The code looks like this.

```
public List<GameObject> bases = new List<GameObject>();
[SyncVar]
public Texture redTexture;
[SyncVar]
public Texture blueTexture;
[SyncVar]
GameObject objID;
NetworkIdentity objNetID;
public void CheckTexture()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bases.Count; ++i)
        {
            var tempScript = bases[i].GetComponent<BaseScoreScript>();
            if (tempScript.owner == "blue")
            {
                objID = bases[i];
                CmdCheckText(objID, blueTexture);
            }
        }
    }
}
 [ClientRpc]
void RpcChangeTexture(GameObject obj, Texture text)
{
    obj.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = text;
}
[Command]
void CmdCheckText(GameObject obj, Texture texture)
{
    objNetID = obj.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();
    objNetID.AssignClientAuthority(connectionToClient);
    RpcChangeTexture(obj, texture);
    objNetID.RemoveClientAuthority(connectionToClient);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191207/unet-multi-player-game-having-both-players-interact-with-gameobject-changes-sy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for any who look at this. I solved the issue. Probably not the most efficient, I can work on that later. But I added a [Command] to the non player object (which does have a NetworkIdentidy and set to local player), in this command I reference a list of players in the scene and set a public variable in the playersscript (which is a SyncVar <- that what did it). And in the playerscript I reference that non Player object and set its texture to the one I wanted. Not worried if it isLocalPlayer or not, because I want all players to see the change.

```
[Command]
void CmdSyncOwner(string own)
{
    //List<GameObject> players = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (GameObject obj in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>())
    {
        players.Remove(obj);
        players.Add(obj);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < players.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (players[i].tag.Contains("Ply"))
        {
            players[i].GetComponent<FPSPlayerFunction>().baseOwner = own;
        }
    }
}
```

that's the code in the non-player script and:

```
[SyncVar]
public string baseOwner;

void BaseStatus()
{
    var blue = Color.blue;
    var red = Color.red;

    foreach(GameObject obj in bases)
    {
        if (baseOwner == "blue")
        {
            centBaseStatus.image.color = blue;
            centBaseStatus.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Center Base : "+ baseOwner;
            GameObject.Find("CenterBase").GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = BlueBase;
        }

    }
}
```

for the playerscrip.
I know its not pretty. But yea, if you have any suggestions on better ways to do this, please let me know. And if this is helpful to someone... Awesome Sauce!